# Rails: Nested form with STI inheritance informing forms, how to make work with AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Okay, first and foremost, I am doing something very complicated. It's possible I've gone in a wrong direction.

What I currently have is a STI inheritance model, StateDescription.  Subclasses of StateDescription describe a specific state I could care about, such as "LocationHasItem" or "ItemNearOtherItem" or what not.

I understand that I may eventually want to upgrade this to a multi-table inheritance model, as not all subclasses of StateDescription use all possible variables (though there is a high degree of overlap).

These StateDescriptions are owned by another class in a "has_many/belongs_to" relationship.

So, inside the form for this other class, I have:

```
<%= f.fields_for :conditions do |e| %>  
        <br> 
        <%= render :partial =>"/state_descriptions/form", :locals => {:e => e, :universe => @story_section.universe, :div_id => "condition"}%>
        <Br>
      <% end %>
```

The StateDescription itself checks for which type it should render, then renders the appropriate partial like so (only showing one subclass, for clarity's sake):

```
<div id="<%=div_id%><%=e.object.id%>">
          <li>
            <%= e.select(:type, StateDescription.subclasses.collect{|x| x.to_s}) %>

            <br>
            <%= e.label "Inverted?" %>
            <%= e.check_box :invert %>
            <Br>
        <% if e.object.type.to_s == "StateDescription::ItNear" %>
           <%= render :partial =>"/state_description/it_nears/form", :locals => {:e => e, :universe => universe, :div_id => div_id}%>
        <% end %>
            <% end %>

            </li>
  </div>
```

The subclass partial looks like:

```
<%=e.collection_select 'item_id', universe.items, :id, :title%>
<%= e.object.title_middle_fragment%>
<%=e.collection_select 'item2_id',universe.items, :id, :title%>
```

Thus the form starts out the same for all subclasses, and only differs as required.

This works PERFECTLY and I was very happy with it...until I decided I wanted to have ajax update the webpage with the correct form when the sublclass is chosen out of select input field.

Then I realized I couldn't pass the form helper reference ("e" in this case) to the partial from a controller.

IS there a best practice for this case, or I am just doing something so complicated I should do straight jQuery or something and leave rails out of it?

If I put the entire form (including the things each subclass has in common) in each subclasses form, that doesn't seem very dry.  Not only that, I'm not sure that I would be able to then associate the StateDescription subclass back up to the parent class...

But, if I do it AJAX, I suppose I could not worry about nested forms and just have the parent be a hidden field or something, and have the StateDescriptions save on their own through AJAX?

Would this be the best solution (if it even works?) or is there some simple Rails way that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know if this is the easiest, or DRYist way to do it, but I ended up putting the whole form in the partial, and then just not bothering with nested forms. This worked just fine with the AJAX solution.

It makes me sad to repeat the form elements they have in common every time, but it's worth it for the AJAX functionality.

I'll try making a bit more DRY, it occurs to me I could try making the subclass partial not need a form, but it could still call a super class form partial to insert the elements each subclass has in common.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with STI model, which is owned by another class in a "has_many/belongs_to" relationship. In order to build the form for this other class dynamically, I used `cocoon` gem, together with `simple_form`.

Cocoon adds methods that dynamically add/remove fields for each concrete class, that inherits from your base STI class.

For example (Publication is the owner class, Item is the base STI model, and Post, Video and Image inherit from it):

```
# _form.html.haml

= simple_form_for @publication, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|

  = f.simple_fields_for :items do |item|
    = render 'item_fields', :f => item
    = link_to_add_association 'Add a Post', f, :items, :wrap_object => Proc.new { |item| item = Item.new }
    = link_to_add_association 'Add an Image', f, :items, :wrap_object => Proc.new { |item| item = Image.new }
    = link_to_add_association 'Add a Video', f, :items, :wrap_object => Proc.new { |item| item = Video.new }

    = f.button :submit, :disable_with => 'Please wait ...', :class => "btn btn-primary", :value => 'Save'
```

The `:wrap_object` proc passes the concrete class to `item_fields` which renders the correct partials, such as `image_fields` or `video_fields` or whatever.

I hope this helps.

I wrote a longer explanation for this problem at: http://www.powpark.com/blog/programming/2014/05/07/rails_nested_forms_for_single_table_inheritance_associations